# KeePassXC Snap System Tray Icon missing in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, snap, system-tray, keepassxc

I have installed KeePassXC from Snap but its system tray icon is missing. It's clickable but only that icon doesn't show up.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-33-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Precision 5510
```

```
KeePassXC - Version 2.7.5
Revision: 6165975
Distribution: Snap

Qt 5.15.8
Debugging mode is disabled.

Operating system: Ubuntu Core 22
CPU architecture: x86_64
Kernel: linux 6.2.0-33-generic

Enabled extensions:
- Auto-Type
- Browser Integration
- SSH Agent
- KeeShare
- YubiKey
- Secret Service Integration

Cryptographic libraries:
- Botan 2.19.1
```